# URL Rewrite => Variable to Subdomain

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomain

In my .htaccess file, this code works fine :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.com$   

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/profile.php?username=%1 [R,L]
```

For example, when I write this URL :

```
http://XXX.mydomain.com
```

It redirects to :

```
http://mydomain.com/profile.php?username=XXX
```

BUT the problem is that I simply want the opposite :

When I write the URL :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=XXX
```

I want a redirection to :

```
http://XXX.mydomain.com
```

I tried all the possibilities, but nothing worked.

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Did my answer help? Have you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=%1 [L]
```

Okay, `www` has now been made optional.

***EDIT:*** To redirect `sub.domain.com/someother/page.php` as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(profile\.php)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

This would redirect

```
eli.mydomain.com => http://www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=eli
eli.mydomain.com/profile.php => http://www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=eli

eli.mydomain.com/contactus.php => http://www.mydomain.com/contactus.php
eli.mydomain.com/help/search.php?q=faq => http://www.mydomain.com/help/search.php?q=faq
```

Comment: That don't work again.

I want the "www" for all the URL but not for those : [http://xxx.mydomain.com]

Your code redirect the url : [http://xxx.mydomain.com] to [http://www.mydomain.com/index.php]

Comment: @Eli It's actually doing quite the opposite! Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess because my rule does not fire for `sub.mydomain.com`. Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: For sure : SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/profile.php?username=%1 [R,L]

Comment: @Eli I don't think what you've posted matches my answer. Both RewriteCond and RewriteRule do not match what I've posted in my answer. You'll have to change the rules to see that they work!

Comment: It was my original .htaccess but by testing yours I have deleted both of my RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have any overriding RewriteRules in your `httpd.conf`. This could be the case since my rules could fail but *they won't* redirect `sub.domain.com` to `index.php?username=sub`.

Comment: If the opposite work, I think that my httpd.conf is well configured. Right ?

Comment: Yes, I think your `httpd.conf` (RewriteRules under <Directory> tags) may be interfering with your `.htaccess`.

Comment: When i'm trying : RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/profile.php?username=%1 **[P]**    It works !!!! My last problem is that I can't write any URL with the "www". Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Isn't this new requirement completely opposite to what you've stated in your question? In your question you wrote: `I want a redirection to http://XXX.mydomain.com`.

Comment: By using this code I can go to XXX.mydomain.com and it redirects to this URL www.mydomain.com/profile.php?username=XXX by hidding this one. The adress bar only displays the URL XXX.mydomain.com and it's prettier. But now, my website read "www" as a variable and the URL www.mydomain.com display the hidden page mydomain.com/profile.php?username=www. The only URL working is //mydomain.com. Do you have a solution if i want to use the **www** for the other URL of my website ?

Comment: What should happen if you try to access `http://xxx.domain.com/somefolder/somepage.php`?

Comment: Any URL which begin with **XXXX** like  XXXX.domain.com/somefolder/somepage.php displays the hidden URL XXXX.domain.com/profile.php?username=XXXXX

Comment: The hidden url shouldn't have XXXX in domain.com right? it should be www. is that correct?

Comment: Really really good job ! Thank you very much ! The last problem is when I'm writing XXXXX.domain.com/another_page.php, i constantly see the page XXXXX.domain.com (XXXX.domain.com/profile.php?username=XXXXX). How can i do to apply those htaccess rules only for the profile.php page ?

Comment: Ah man, this is what I had asked half an hour ago! `What should happen if you try to access http://xxx.domain.com/somefolder/somepage.php?` You keep changing the requirements.. :(

Comment: are other_pages.php same for all users? should user1.domain.com/somepage.jsp and user2.domain.com/somepage.jsp redirect to same www.mydomain.com/somepage.jsp??

Comment: No user1.domain.com/somepage.jsp should redirect to user1.domain.com and user2.domain.com/somepage.jsp should redirect to user2.domain.com

Comment: But user1.domain.com is already getting redirected to www.domain.com/profile.php?user=user1 and that's what you said you don't want! How do you want this to be handled? This way somepage.jsp would get redirected to profile.php in the end!

Comment: When I'm trying to go to XXXXX.domain.com/other_page_of_my_website.php, the URL stays like that and the page displaying is the same as XXXXX.domain.com. How could I display an error page or something else ?